# Haskell `randoms` function not behaving well with my library

Tags: haskell, random

I'm trying to write a Haskell library for cryptographically secure random numbers. The code follows:

```
module URandom (URandom, initialize) where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import System.Random
import Data.Word

newtype URandom = URandom [Word8]

instance RandomGen URandom where
  next (URandom (x : xs)) = (fromIntegral x, URandom xs)
  split (URandom l) = (URandom (evens l), URandom (odds l))
    where evens (x : _ : xs) = x : evens xs
          odds (_ : x : xs) = x : odds xs
  genRange _ = (fromIntegral (minBound :: Word8), fromIntegral (maxBound :: Word8))

initialize :: IO URandom
initialize = URandom . B.unpack <$> B.readFile "/dev/urandom"
```

Unfortunately, it's not behaving like I want. In particular, performing

```
take 10 . randoms <$> initialize
```

yields (something similar to)

```
[-4611651379516519433,-4611644973572935887,-31514321567846,9223361179177989878,-4611732094835278236,9223327886739677537,4611709625714976418,37194416358963,4611669560113361421,-4611645373004878170,-9223329383535098640,4611675323959360258,-27021785867556,9223330964083681227,4611705212636167666]
```

which to my, albiet untrained, eye, does not appear very random. A lot of 46... and 92... in there.

What could be going wrong? Why doesn't this produce well-distributed numbers? It's worth noting that even if I concatenate together `Word8`s to form `Int`s the distribution does not improve, I didn't think it was worth including that code here.

Edit: here's some evidence that's not distributed correctly. I've written a function called histogram:

```
histogram :: ∀ t . (Integral t, Bounded t)
          => [t] -> Int -> S.Seq Int
histogram [] buckets = S.replicate buckets 0
histogram (x : xs) buckets = S.adjust (+ 1) (whichBucket x) (histogram xs buckets)
  where whichBucket x = fromIntegral $ ((fromIntegral x * fromIntegral buckets) :: Integer) `div` fromIntegral (maxBound :: t)
```

and when I run

```
g <- initialize
histogram (take 1000000 $ randoms g :: [Word64]) 16
```

I get back

```
fromList [128510,0,0,121294,129020,0,0,122090,127873,0,0,120919,128637,0,0,121657]
```

Some of the buckets are completely empty!

Comment: Looks random to me. :) I usually use the uniformally distributed random variate from the `mwc-random` package: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.15/mwc-random-0.13.6.0/System-Random-MWC.html#v:uniform

Comment: I think it's more likely that [it is hard for humans to detect randomness](https://cocosci.berkeley.edu/tom/papers/hard.pdf) than that there is a real problem with the random library. I would want to see statistically relevant evidence that the samples are not random before agreeing with you.

Comment: `evens` and `odds` can error, since a list is not always guaranteed to have an even length.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the list is infinite

Comment: The sample you gave looks fishy but I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Programman I can't reproduce your histogram results, for me it gives `[62398,62151,62517,62490,62331,62213,62646,62719,62571,62189,62777,62734,62355,62782,62312,62815]`, which looks highly plausible. What OS are you trying this on?

Comment: Gentoo Linux 64 bit on kernel 4.9.16

Comment: Have you looked at the raw numbers that come out of urandom?

Comment: Yeah they look pretty good. In particular if I change histogram to take a `Word8` instead of a `Word64` all the buckets are about evenly distributed.

Comment: Well according to your hypotheses it seems like there would be a bug in [`randomIvalInteger`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#randomIvalInteger).  Might be worth playing with that function to see if it does indeed have a bug.

Comment: I just tried in on Debian 8 and got the same result as on Gentoo. Could it be a hardware-related issue?

Comment: @leftaroundabout my histogram function is pretty badly written, did you change `Word64` to `Word8` in both places?

Comment: @Programman yeah at first, therefore I changed it (see edit)...

Comment: Since it seems we can't reproduce it, a hardware issue seems likely, but in that case you should be able to observe it from urandom directly. Get a histogram of individual bytes, as buckets may hide irregularities. What is your version of `random`? The latest version (though old) changed things quite a bit, though that may not be it either.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I'm using version 1.0.1.1 of random

Comment: It does show up directly from urandom! See edit

Comment: 512 is twice the number of `Word8` values.

Comment: lol: good point

Comment: You appear to have accidentally reverted that last edit again. — Could you show a direct dump of some of your `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: I can reproduce it with `random-1.0.1.1`.

Comment: Upgrade to 1.1 which implements a better algorithm.

Comment: (@leftaroundabout that wasn't accidental. He was looking at a histogram of generated `Word8` with 512 buckets.)

Comment: @Li-yaoXia that's it! Upgrading to 1.1 fixes the issue.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia -- it would be great if you could post this as an answer, maybe with a reference to or a quote from the ChangeLog regarding the use of a better algorithm.  It is likely to be of help to others and is going to get lost in a sea of comments otherwise.

Comment: Ok sure. I added an answer.

Comment: Not related to your question, but have you read [this paper](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/183348/local_183348.pdf) about splittable PRNG's? Might be useful for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is a bug in `random-1.0.1.1` that was fixed in `random-1.1`. [The changelog](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/changelog) points to [this ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8898). In particular, referring to the older version:

> It also assumes that all RandomGen implementations produce the same range of random values as StdGen.

Here randomness is produced 8 bits at a time, and that caused the observed behavior.

`random-1.1` fixed this:

> This implementation also works with any RandomGen, even ones that produce as little as a single bit of entropy per next call or have a minimum bound other than zero.